# Finding the harmonic conjugate of the function

Tags: complex-analysis, harmonic-analysis, harmonic-functions

> $u(x,y)=e^{x^2-y^2}(e^y \cos(x-2xy)+ e^{-y} \cos(x+2xy))$

Solving the Cauchy-Riemann equations for this is not practical. Alternatively, I could try to express $u(x,y)$ in the form of the real or complex part of a (analytic) function in $z$. In doing that, I either observe it right away, or put in $x=\frac{z+\bar z}{2}$ and $y=\frac{z-\bar z}{2i}$. But that turned really messy and the $z$'s and $\bar z$'s in the coefficients of the exponential functions do not reduce too give the desired form. I would like to ask what else can I do here to find the harmonic conjugate?

Comment: Use the sum-of-angles formula for cosine...?

Comment: I think every approach to find the conjugate involves solving the Cauchy-Riemann at some point. You could try to rewrite the two cosine-terms using $$\cos z = \frac{e^{iz}+e^{-iz}}{2}.$$ Maybe this simplifies the expression of $u$ in a way that makes the differentiation more managable.

Comment: Btw: I noticed that you got answers for many of your questions, but never *accepted* an answer so far. If you are not aware of it: Accepting an answer is important as it both rewards posters for solving your problem and informs others that your issue is resolved. See [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) and [How does accepting an answer work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/196432) for more information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given that $u$ is harmonic, you can simply replace $x$ with $z$ and $y$ with $0$ to get an analytic function which agrees with $u$ on the real axis, and hence everywhere:
$$
f(z) = 2 e^{z^2} \cos z
.
$$
Now just take the imaginary part of $f(x+iy)$.